# using libraries with the same defines in one file

Tags: c++, c, g++

I have a project in which I want to use both grpc and ncurses and I stumbled across a strange error
I have a function

```
grpc::Status test(){
    ...
    return grpc::Status::OK;
}
```

which works fine without ncurses, however if I add

```
#include <ncurses.h>
```

The whole thing breaks  with this error

```
src/main.cc:32:26: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘(’ token
   32 |     return grpc::Status::OK;
      |                          ^~
make: *** [makefile:34: obj/main.o] Error 1
```

As it turn out, ncurses also has

```
#undef OK
#define OK (0)
```

Is there a way to tackle this problem? Here are my ideas of what could work, but I don't know how to implement them.

- namespace mangling
- ifndefs
- different compilation method

I am compiling my program with:

```
g++ -lncurses  -lprotobuf -lgrpc++ -lgrpc++_reflection
```

Comment: Maybe `#undef` it?

Comment: Oh yea, pretty dumb of me to not think about it even though I posted `#undef` in my question, you can post it as answer  if you want full karma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you can just `#undef` it.